# How to use Star rating of Font-awesome with Django?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

[Fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) has a great star rating css extension, which looks really awesome.

However clicking on any of the span elements wouldn't really do anything.  I don't know how to hook this up with my database model. Lets say I have an integer field of 0-5 in Django. How could I set the value according to the user's selection within the template?

[image]

```
<span class="rating">
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Did you add any CSS or just the votes? Did vote turn up with a 0 value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ended up using [Raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty). If you are looking for a simple and clean solution, I found this the easiest.

```
$('#star').raty('score');                   // Get the current score.
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have inserted the github link.

Answer (score 16):

I seen this post, but didn't want to use a plugin with more than I needed. So, I threw this together for a small project I'm working on. You don't need bootstrap to use this.

HTML

```
<div class="star-rating"> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="whatever" class="rating-value" value="3">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.star-rating {
  line-height:32px;
  font-size:1.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

CoffeeScript

```
$star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa')

SetRatingStar = ->
  $star_rating.each ->
    if parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))
      $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star')
    else
      $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o')

$star_rating.on 'click', ->
    $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val $(this).data('rating')
    SetRatingStar()

SetRatingStar()
```

Javascript:

```
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function() {
  return $star_rating.each(function() {
    if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
  $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
  return SetRatingStar();
});

SetRatingStar();
```

Comment: The coffeescript code does exactly the same thing as the javascript code.

Answer (score 12):

This is the best plugin for star rating if you are using bootstrap:

- 2Kb minified
- Use Bootstrap Glyphicons
- No extra CSS
- You just have to add `class="rating"` to the input

[Github Project](https://github.com/javiertoledo/bootstrap-rating-input)

Answer (score 10):

I did not see a simple answer using only bootstrap glyphicons and jquery. I am sure other people have come here looking for a quick copy and paste so I just wrote one.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.rating-select .btn').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
        $(this).prevAll().removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default');
    });

    $('.rating-select').on('mouseleave', function(){
        active = $(this).parent().find('.selected');
        if(active.length) {
            active.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
            active.prevAll().removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
            active.nextAll().removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.btn').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default');
        }
    });

    $('.rating-select .btn').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $('.rating-select .selected').removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('.rating-select .selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating-select">
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
</div>
```

To set the default value from the DB using django template, for each star do:

```
<div class="btn btn-{% if rate.value > 0 %}warning{% else %}default{% endif %}{% if rate.value == 1 %} selected{% endif %} btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
```

Comment: 1+. Lol about "quick copy and paste"  . Your code look good, thinking about copying it

Answer (score 7):

One more interesting method. Pure CSS, keeps selected value, uses radio-buttons (cool!) and FA fonts

[See demo](http://codepen.io/Funstarter/pen/pJZooM)

Taken from [this post](http://habrahabr.ru/post/262833/)

HTML

```
<div class="star-rating">
  <div class="star-rating__wrap">
    <input class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
    <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-5" title="5 out of 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
    <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-4" title="4 out of 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
    <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-3" title="3 out of 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
    <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-2" title="2 out of 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
    <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-1" title="1 out of 5 stars"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.star-rating{
    font-size: 0;
}
.star-rating__wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.star-rating__wrap:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.star-rating__ico{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFB300;
}
.star-rating__ico:last-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}
.star-rating__input{
    display: none;
}
.star-rating__ico:hover:before,
.star-rating__ico:hover ~ .star-rating__ico:before,
.star-rating__input:checked ~ .star-rating__ico:before
{
    content: "\f005";
}
```

Comment: How would you set the amount of stars on page load with this?

Answer (score 6):

You may check my [Bootstrap JQuery Star rating plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) I created with various configurable options (demos for scenarios are included within). It uses CSS3 as much as possible, but also uses JQuery (if you are ok with that). You can get the star rating numbers OR set it easily through the plugin methods.

Uses Bootstrap 3.x glyphicons, includes RTL support, supports plugin events and methods. The plugin also supports any fractionally filled stars. You can refer the [source here](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating).

If you are keen on using Font-Awesome, you can override the plugin CSS to use Font-Awesome instead of Bootstrap Glyphicons in your project.

Answer (score 2):

[Font Awesome and JQuery DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eniebla/aha95663/4/)

HTML

```
<div>Rating Star - Function CallBack onChange</div>
<div class="well well-sm">
    <span id="rating_1" class="rating" ></span>
    <span id="result_1"></span> 
</div>
<div>Rating Star - No Editable</div>
<div class="well well-sm">
    <span id="rating_2" class="rating" data-val="2.49" data-stars='6' data-change="false"></span>
    <span>Calificaste con <b>2.49</b> de <b>6</b> Estrellas</span> 
</div>
<div>Rating Star - Tamaño - Data Html options -- Hidden input</div>
<div class="well well-sm">
   <span id="rating_3" class="rating" data-val="2.49" data-stars='10' data-input=".rating-value" data-change="true" style="font-size:35px;" >
        <input type="hidden" name="whatever3" class="rating-value" size="5"  />
   </span>
</div>
<div>Rating Star - javascript Options - input text</div>
<div class="well well-sm">
   <span id="rating_4" class="rating">
       <input type="text" name="whatever4" id="rating_val" size="1" readOnly="readOnly" />    
   </span>
    <span id="result_4"> &nbsp;&nbsp;de <b>10</b> estrellas </span> 
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 $('#rating_1').RatingStar(
   {callback:function(val){$('#result_1').html(" &nbsp;"+val+" estrella(s).")}}
 );

 $('#rating_2').RatingStar();

 $('#rating_3').RatingStar();

 $('#rating_4').RatingStar({
     val:4.95,
     stars:10,
     input:'#rating_val',
     change:true
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $star_rating = $('.rating .star');

var SetRatingStar = function() {
  return $star_rating.each(function() {


var puan = document.formname.whatever.value;



    if ( parseInt($(this).data('rating')) <= puan) {
      return $(this).removeClass('star').addClass('star filled');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('star filled').addClass('star');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() { 

  document.formname.whatever.value=$(this).data('rating');

  return SetRatingStar();
});



.rating{unicode-bidi:bidi-override;direction:rtl;font-size:10px;}
.rating span.star{font-family:FontAwesome;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;display:inline-block}
.rating span.star:hover{cursor:pointer}
.rating span.star:before{content:"\f006";padding-right:5px;color:#999}
.rating span.star:hover:before,.rating span.star:hover~span.star:before{content:"\f005";color:#e3cf7a}
.rating span.star.filled {}
.rating span.star.filled:before{content:"\f005";color:#e3cf7a; }



<span class="rating" style="font-size:20px;">
<span class="star" data-rating="5"></span><span class="star" data-rating="4"></span><span class="star" data-rating="3"></span><span class="star" data-rating="2"></span><span class="star" data-rating="1"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [django-ratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) - that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, its looking good, but I came across an issue. May you please have a look at the updated question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution. The stars are based only on the numbers, so the search engine and the browser just reads **4.5 out of 5** and that's all. It uses [my own custom font](http://socialblogsitewebdesign.com/semantic-yet-seo-friendly-rating-stars/); no JS, no SVG, no Flash, no Canvas. It's also [available as a progress bar](http://socialblogsitewebdesign.com/semantic-yet-seo-friendly-graph-bar/).

[**DEMO/CODE**](http://codepen.io/socialblogsite/pen/diBjD)

Here the code, without the microformat tags to make it simpler:

```
Rating: <span class="star-rating-icons">
<strong>3.5</strong> out of <i>5</i>
</span>
```

And here's the CSS that includes the font and the relevant styling:

```
.star-rating-icons {
    font-family: seostars;
  font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: .6em;
    position: relative;
    width: 5em;
    text-indent: -5000px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
}
.star-rating-icons strong {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    color: #FC0;
    font-family: seostars;
    text-indent: 0;
}
.star-rating-icons strong:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.star-rating-icons i {
    color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #666;
    left: 0;
}
```

Basically the first-letter of the rating is formatted with a character with that amount of whole stars, and the decimal with the partial stars. The outline of the stars is made out of the period, although it could be applied to any other character present. (By editing the font or just with a pseudo element)

Comment: would you care to comment how it works? The `how it works` on your blog is pretty obscure. What font does it use? what's the css?

Comment: I'm sorry for the "obscurity". I assumed everyone knows how to use "developer tools" or some "inspector" or just "source code". You can check the code at [codepen](http://codepen.io/socialblogsite/pen/diBjD) And as per how it works… it uses a special font to render the integer (first-letter), another font for the decimal, and the dot makes the stars "frame".

Comment: Really? -5 votes for a simple non-JS solution? What's the complicated thing about :first-letter and position:absolute ?
Custom fonts have been around for years too.

Comment: It seems that the negative rating is more because this cannot be used to set the value of the stars, it's simply a method to display the stars.

Comment: Yeah uh, this was EXACTLY what I wanted and the demo is prety good. Not sure why so much hate.

Comment: Just wanted to write back and used this for my STEM presentation tomorrow, and it worked like a champ aftre looking at the demo for less than 5 minutes..

Comment: I updated the demos for those who get it sold with glitter will like it. When you see the demos again, remember: It's the SAME thing you hated, haha. Don't be afraid of special fonts and first-letter work. http://codepen.io/socialblogsite/pen/diBjD
Thanks @Yablargo for the comment. Some people get nasty when they are given caviar and they don't know how to eat it hehe

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Star Ratings With Very Little CSS](http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) from CssTricks. It uses no images, no Bootstrap, no Javascript. Pure CSS and Unicode stars, see [this](http://copypastecharacter.com/). Supported by all browsers except IE <= 6.

*Note: Javascript is not required for UI, but is required for sending data to the server and preserving the rating selection after the element loses focus.*

Also take a look at [Accessible star rating widget with pure CSS](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/). It is a pure CSS as well. Uses a technique discussed here - [Custom radio and checkbox inputs using CSS](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css). It's different from the first one in a way that the rating stays selected after the element loses the focus. Unfortunately, it is supported by fewer browsers.

A quick note on [CSS Selectors](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) might be useful while reading that.

**UPDATE:**

Have just reread the post and clicked the link. The first link in my answer is the same as topic starter's. Apologies.

Anyway, I chose not to delete the answer, as it contains a few links which I've been very glad to find and which might be useful for others.