# Any good star rating libraries or plugins that are fast that don't need jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My page has a loop that will loop through maybe couple dozen results and display them. Each result will have a star-rating. So I'm looking for a simple tag which I can include in my html page where I can provide a property for the number of stars filled (ex: **tag data-star-number=4**) and it would display 4 filled stars out of 5.

I've seen some html that looks like this from the [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762995/how-to-use-star-rating-of-font-awesome-with-django) but I'm a little overwhelmed by everything that's out there. I'd like to use bootstrap and possibly font awesome because they are both already heavily used in my app. What's the best plugin for just plugging a tag with a class to use on my page?

```
<span class="rating">
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: please take a look at http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Comment: how do you plan to put these results onto the page/build the page dynamically?

Comment: What do u mean dynamically? This is a page that gets displayed after I enter in something in a search box, I get redirected to the results page and a loop goes through each result. There are probably a few dozen results on the page and each one will have a int value that can represent the rating. So I don't want to perform any logic, I just want to take the rating value and plug it into a attribute or something and have it show the stars. It doesn't have to work just like this, I just don't want to run through any logic on the page and I don't want to perform any jquery logic after page load.

Comment: I looked at the link above but I don't think this will work in my case. This example sets the rating by hovering, I will be feeding a value when I render my view that will give it a rating that won't be modifiable.

Comment: like Yelp! how does Yelp display all their ratings fast, without performing some logic or minimal logic on each rating as it loops through each result?

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS solution, better and lighter than any library :

```css
.star {
    color: orange;
}
.star1:before {
    content : '★'
}
.star2:before {
    content : '★★'
}
.star3:before {
    content : '★★★'
}
```

etc

```html
<span class="star star1"></span>
<span class="star star2"></span>
<span class="star star3"></span>
```

and so on, demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0vffnwkw/**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use angular, I came up with something that might work for you: 
https://jsfiddle.net/15bu2qsk/1/

Edit for newer versions of angular: https://jsfiddle.net/15bu2qsk/2/

It's a simple angular directive that allows you to use tags.

```
 <star-rating stars=3></star-rating>
```

It can be used as such:

```
<html ng-app="myApp"> 

<head>
    <title>Star Rating Directive</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body> 
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.directive('starRating', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                stars: '=stars'
            },
            template: "<span ng-repeat='i in getTimes(stars) track by $index' class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>",
            link: function ($scope) {
                $scope.getTimes = function (n) {
                    return new Array(n);
                };
            }
        };
    });
</script> 

<star-rating stars=3></star-rating>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are already using Angular, this should be ok. I wouldn't use angular only for this specifically, as it would add too much overhead vs. functionality.

Answer (score 0):

here is the best answer I found for what I need - pure css where I can just assign a number to get the stars filled. http://codepen.io/Bluetidepro/pen/GkpEa

```css
.star-ratings-css {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
  
  .star-ratings-css-top {
    color: #e7711b;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #ab5414;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .star-ratings-css-bottom { z-index: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 68%"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span>
  </div>
</div>
```